# What is Eclipse Ctrl+1 shortcut equivalent in Android Studio?

Tags: eclipse, android-studio

I really like the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> shortcut (hints for errors and mini refactorings) in Eclipse. Is there an equivalent for it in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

I know i am pretty late but might help someone else . It's Alt + Enter in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> was one of my favorite shortcuts but unfortunately the is no exact equivalent shortcut for that. You can search for Quick fix in: `File-->Settings-->Keymap`, but you'll find nothing.

Although many people would say <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> is the nearest answer. but I think there are better equivalents such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>. It will give you some magic options.

You can also remap it to  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> if you want.